# Difference between Shutdown-app & kill-app in Apache Apex CLI commands

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, stream-processing, apache-apex, bigdata

can someone help me understand, what is the difference between Shutdown-app & kill-app in Apache APEX CLI commands ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shutdown-app would call tearDown() methods of respective operators and wait for some time for operators to have graceful shutdown.

Whereas, kill-app is like force-kill for all the operators. Thus, this will stop the application immediately. But, operators will not get any chance for the cleanup activity.

In both the cases, YARN would release resources allocated for that application after app is brought down.

Comment: Also, one more quick question, can you help me with the command to resume the application which is shutdown with shutdown-app command ?

Comment: Could you please post this as a separate question?

Comment: @Raja, here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37784367/how-to-restart-apache-apex-application/37784368#37784368