# How to restart Apache Apex application?

Tags: stream-processing, apache-apex

From the [apex documentation](http://apex.apache.org/docs/apex/), it is clear that an app launched with apache apex can be killed or shutdwon using the commands: `kill-app` & `shutdown-app` respectively.

But, when the application is turned off (shutdown/kill), how to restart it from its previous state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache Apex](https://apex.apache.org/) provides a command line interface, "apex" (previously called "dtcli") script, to interact with the applications. Once an application is shut down or killed, you can restart it using following command:

`launch   pi-demo-3.4.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.apa   -originalAppId application_1465560538823_0074   -Ddt.attr.APPLICATION_NAME="Relaunched PiDemo"   -exactMatch "PiDemo"`

where,

> `-originalAppId` is ID of the original app. This will ensure that the operators continue from where the original app left-off.
>
> `-Ddt.attr.APPLICATION_NAME` gives the new name for relaunched app
>
> `-exactMatch` is used to specify the exact app name

Note that, `-Ddt.attr.APPLICATION_NAME` & `-exactMatch` are optional.